# Econometrics online learning course

Tags: self-study, econometrics, learning, internet

i would kindly like to ask you for recommendations regarding introductory, but more importantly advanced online econometrics courses (theory as well as applied, preferably in R). I would be most interested in free courses if possible.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Best,
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Phil as a fellow economics disciple, I would like to say that book is always the best material for the learning, but the online course is the complimentary or an enhancement for learning process.

I give you both the Youtube channels that pretty much sum up all the econometric course for undergrad and master and the books. The links are below, if you prefer mathematic you can just go ahead and watch master course.

For the R programming, if you are already familiar with the STATA, you can just learn R from any where that related to the statistical model used in econometrics. But I would recommend books instead.

Applied Econometrics with R

The greatest one for econ student to learn R, this will take a lot of time to digest into you brain so give it a time. If you are new with R programming you should learn the material separately by going through econometric theory first and then R.

Introduction to statistical learning with R

This one pretty much give you the intuition of how to create and build the Logistic regression, and linear regression but not account for the violation of Gauss Markov assumption. It is not that good for econ student but it give you much more insight about data.

Applied predictive model

This one is pretty much straight to the point for forecasting

[master]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMVh02WGhoc&list=PLwJRxp3blEvaxmHgI2iOzNP6KGLSyd4dz

[undergrad]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_5SLG7sUa0&list=PLwJRxp3blEvZyQBTTOMFRP_TDaSdly3gU

[statistics in R]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=riONFzJdXcs&list=PLqzoL9-eJTNBDdKgJgJzaQcY6OXmsXAHU

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* there is a lot of courses branded as "statistics" or "data science", while not many as "econometrics", so try the two former keywords. The topics covered by such courses would overlap to great extent with econometrics. Moreover, such courses would cover a general set of skills for working with data, data analytics, and modelling, so they would surely be useful for econometrics as well.